# Insert data error

Tags: vb.net

I got an error saying you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES ('001','Roldan', 'Matre', 'A', 'Manila', '19', 'Male', 'matre@gmail.com', '099999999' )at line 1

my code

```
 Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
Private Sub TextBox6_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles contact.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Add_Patient_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save.Click


   MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;userid=root;password=theazt15><;database=database"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = " INSERT INTO patient_info (Patient_Id,Surname,Firstname,MI,Address, Age, Gender, Email, Contact_No.) VALUES ('" & id.Text & "' , '" & surname.Text & "' , '" & firstname.Text & "' , '" & mi.Text & "' , '" & address.Text & "', '" & age.Text & "' , '" & gender.Text & "' , '" & email.Text & "' , '" & contact.Text & "'  )"

        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("Patient Saved")




        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: Use sql parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.  Do you really have a period for Contact_No.?

Comment: Rewrite that using SQL parameters and the problem will likely evaporate.  Is everything text?  Why are you assigning the ID from a text box - thats the job of the Database

Comment: I do have in my database

Comment: what do I need to do ?

Comment: @Edrey Ching  The result of concatenating a string to create SQL statement, this will always cause issues.. Consider using parameters for your values instead... here is a good simple example... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553360/incorrect-syntax-near-vb-net-with-sql-database

Comment: I removed the period  in my database and its okay now , thank you guys !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

. is extra i think in contact_no