# I have an error in missing operator?

Tags: vb.net

Please help me, don't know what to do about it. Just would like to update the information. But this is the error 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'
this is my actual code:

```
            str = "UPDATE Expenses SET TuitionFee = @TFee, BookFee = @Bfee, MiscellaneousFee = @Mfee, OtherFee = @Ofee WHERE YearLevel = @YL"
    mycmd = New OleDbCommand(str, conn)

    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YL", txtYearLevel.Text)
    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TFee", txtTFee.Text)
    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bfee", txtBFee.Text)
    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mfee", txtMFee.Text)
    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ofee", txtOFee.Text)

    mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: So you have a code that is not compiling and ask us to help you, fine, but wait... where is the code?

Comment: I can't upload the picture

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to build sql queries, Use always the parameters collection of the OleDbCommand.

Comment: ohhh, okay, i'll' try it. Thanks

Comment: A part from the previous comment, what is the datatype of the FIELD YearLevel? and what is the text of cmbYearLevel?

Comment: my datatype from the Access is Text, and the text is "Grade 1"

Comment: I don't want you to use a bad practice but did you notice how the other strings are enclosed between single quotes? Anyway, use the parameters collection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I can't understand how I will implement it on my code. Sorry I'm just a beginner

Comment: @silentstorm21 you will always have problems when concatenating strings to create SQL query, it is proberbly the number one issue that comes up over and over. Here is a good (simple) example (7 up-vots so far but the asker didn't select it as the answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553360/incorrect-syntax-near-vb-net-with-sql-database and there are some useful links there too.

Comment: @monty Thank you for another answer, but I really can't use it well. is it like this? '
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@YearLevel", txtYearLevel.Text).Value.ToString()'

Comment: Try.. mycmd.Parameters.Add("@YearLevel", SqlDbType.string).Value = txtYearLevel.Text

Comment: Add this in your txtYearLevel.Text field... `; DROP Expenses;`... and execute your command... Not only is it important to have params, but the actual Data type in your parameter may just save your a$$ in the long run...

Comment: @Codexer, hi I can't understand how

Comment: like this?         mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearLevel", txtYearLevel.Text; DROP Expenses;).ToString()

Comment: Type that in the actual textbox... Not really if you don't want to loose the table...

Comment: the moment I run it i will enter that?

Comment: Yes....if you want to actually drop a table...

Comment: I just would like to update my table. not drop it

Comment: I understand that, my comment was directed at possible injection and you should specify the Data Type it's important.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement specified a parameter named `OFee`, but you don't supply it.  You DO supply one named `OtherFee` though, Looks to me like you got the names confused.

Change:

```
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherFee", txtYearLevel.Text)
```

To this:

```
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OFee", txtYearLevel.Text)
```

While not that cause of this error, you are setting all your parameters to the same value, this is most likely incorrect.  Also, pay attention to all the comments about parameterized queries, this is VERY important to learn.

---

Upon closer inspection I noticed you are using `OleDbCommand` which doesn't support named parameters.  You have to specify them with `?` instead, and add them in the same order as the SQL statement. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example: SELECT * FROM
>   Customers WHERE CustomerID = ? Therefore, the order in which
>   OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must
>   directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder
>   for the parameter in the command text.

Comment: I changed yet, it's still the same

Comment: Ahh, I just noticed that you are uing `OleDbCommand` not `SqlCommand`. OleDb doesn't support named params, you have to use `?` instead. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx.  I've updated my answer with more details.